# How to set a non default zstd compression level at btrfs filesystem defragment?

Tags: btrfs, zstd

```
# btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -czstd:15 /
ERROR: unknown compression type zstd:15
# btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -czstd_15 /
ERROR: unknown compression type zstd_15
# btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -czstd15 /
ERROR: unknown compression type zstd15
```

The [btrfs manual page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-filesystem) doesn't give the clue on how to select a compression level:

> **-c[algo]**
>
> compress file contents while defragmenting. Optional argument selects the compression algorithm, zlib (default), lzo or zstd.
>   Currently it’s not possible to select no compression. See also section
>   EXAMPLES.

How to select a non-default zstd compression level to re-compress existing btrfs filesystems?

---

Note: [`btrfs filesystem defragment` on **snapshots** might result in much larger disk space consumption](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400225/btrfs-is-it-dangerous-to-defragment-subvolume-which-has-readonly-snapshots/413430#413430):

> Warning: Defragmenting with Linux kernel versions < 3.9 or ≥ 3.14-rc2
>   as well as with Linux stable kernel versions ≥ 3.10.31, ≥ 3.12.12 or ≥
>   3.13.4 **will break up the ref-links of COW data** (for example files copied with cp --reflink, snapshots or de-duplicated data). This may
>   cause **considerable increase of space usage** depending on the broken up
>   ref-links.

Comment: Relevant issue on GitHub: https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/issues/184

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kernel 5.1 added ZSTD level support. I tested it with rc1 today using a mount option compress=zstd:12 in /etc/fstab. The default level is 3. To be clear: The change affects only files that are written after this mount command. Some benchmark results: https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/1/28/1930

Comment: Trying to set any level fails: `open_ctree failed`

Comment: Which kernel version and which Linux distribution?

Comment: When was the btrfs filesystem created (maybe with a too old version)?

Comment: I can't remember exactly but I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and the installation is only about a year old. Alexander's answer below works for me. I'll try again when I update the system.

Comment: Being able to mount with a level specification does not mean that defrag accepts it. Tested with openSUSE Leap 15.3 (5.3.18 kernel with backports) and btrfs-progs v4.19.1 using `zlib:6`.

Answer (score 5):

Not yet (December 28th, 2017) possible:

> Q: Can I set the compression level?
>
> #### A: …, ZSTD level support is planned.

source: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression

Answer (score 4):

Try:

> $> sudo mount -o remount,compress=zlib:9,compress=zstd /

After that command '*findmnt*' displays '**compress=zstd:9**' mount option :)

Comment: I am wondering, does this also better zstd compress files then default zstd? And how was that verified? Or is this only a display glitch?