# how does btrfs' copy-on-write feature influence with database application(such as postgresSQL)?

Tags: performance, btrfs, database

I'm working on manjaro KDE whoes whoal `/` partition (excepting /boot/efi partition, of course) has formated to btrfs filesystem, and its copy-on-write feature remains default.
Just now, I was following Arch wiki to install postgres, and I notice something that I don't quite understand:

```
#https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL

Warning:
If the database resides on a Btrfs file system, you should consider disabling Copy-on-Write for the directory before creating any database.
```

I've searched in Google, but what I see seems to tell me COW will reduce performance to database. But how does that happen? COW should reduce I/O delay, is't it?

P.S. English is not my first language. There maybe some syntax mistakes. Please forgive me.

wish all you best.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow through the links [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL) > [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Btrfs#Copy-on-Write_(CoW)) > [finally here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Copy_on_Write_.28CoW.29) you might see these words:

> Some people insist that Btrfs does "Redirect-on-write" rather than "Copy-on-write" because Btrfs is based on a scheme for redirect-based updates of B-trees by Ohad Rodeh, and because understanding the code is easier with that mindset.

The upshot of this is that copy-on-write writes the new data somewhere else and leaves a redirect.  This causes fragmentation of the file on disk.  There's a discussion about it in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395013/20140

When you combine this with postgresql's behaviour (like most modern DBMS) the result is very undesirable because postgresql will make a lot of "random" writes to very large files.  btrfs will badly fragment those files.

Worse postgresql is already very optimised.  It tries to plan it's reads to caused a minimal amount of disk-seek.  It also tries to keep table data collected together on the same place on disk while writing rows.  If you fragment its files across a disk you interfere with its ability to collect reads together and ultimately slow it down.

In postgresql there's a process called [Vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html).  One of the jobs of Vacuum is to try to keep data for the same table roughly collected together.  If you turn on copy-on-write, this process could actually have the exact opposite effect, spreading the data widely across the disk.

---

I'll also note that if you are using very fast SSD drives, the cost of fragmentation has been somewhat reduced, but does still exist.

On magnetic storage the cost is enormous.  Magnetic disks can read many MB in one go with microscopic movements.  But if the data is fragmented, the disk heads must "seek" to a new position and this takes a very long time (in computing terms).